# I'm having trouble returning a certain output based on the number I input into the textfield

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to return a certain output in the div container whenever someone enters a number greater than 0 in the input textfield and hits the submit button. I am unsure of what I am doing incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Button Magic</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Jquery.css'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Input Field-->
<input type="text" id="first" maxlength="6" placeholder="0.00">

<!-- Span -->
<span>< Type here</span>

<!-- Submit -->
<button onclick="submitNumber()">Submit</button>

<!-- Output -->
<div id="textOutput">
Are you correct?
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function submitNumber() {

textInput = document.getElementById('first');
textOutput = document.getElementById('textOutput');

if (textInput > 0) {
textOutput.innerHTML = 'Correct!';
} else {
textOutput.innerHTML = 'Incorrect!';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('first')` returns a dom element, not the value of the input field, you need to read the `value` property of the input element

```
textInput = document.getElementById('first').value;
textOutput = document.getElementById('textOutput');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8nPCk/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the value of the DOM element in the variable `textInput`, you are checking for the element `document.getElementById('first')`) instead, you can get the value of the input element using the `.value` property:

```
if (textInput.value > 0) {
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz7bY/)**